# ¿Cómo utilizar función number_format en fetch(...)?

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Me encuentro definiendo una promesa `.then()` y en ella necesito utilizar la función `number_format` para mostrar el dato de una consulta.
En el video tutorial que estuve viendo utilizo `${}` para poder mostrar el dato, pero tengo una duda ya que en otro sitio del mismo proyecto yo realizo la llamada al dato por medio de php para mostrarlo en el html, ej:

```
<label><?php echo number_format($gli['precio'], 2, '.', '') ?></label>
```

ahora como estoy viendo en el video obtengo el dato de la siguiente manera:

```
${datosPRD.data[i].precio}
```

y **tengo la duda sobre el cómo utilizar dicha función** ya que según yo no estoy mostrando datos de php para utilizar el `<?php echo number_format(${datosPRD.data[i].precio}, 2, '.', '') ?>` que es lo que se me ocurrió al principio

si alguien me puede ayudar en este tema le agradezco bastante ya que todavía no encuentro alguna documentación y también sobre como concatenar variables para poner como atributo de identificación a la etiqueta [`id=" ${datosPRD.data[i].nombre}.','. number_format(${datosPRD.data[i].precio}, 2, '.', '')`  ]

link del video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_CwG8xaE74&list=PL01E36290C73C6D0F&index=108&t=691s&ab_channel=CODERNAUTA

Comment: Tal parece que tienes mezclados los conceptos de PHP con JavaScript. Toma en cuenta que PHP se ejecuta siempre en el lado Servidor y JavaScript en el lado cliente. Esto significa que no puedes intercambiar directamente funcionalidades entre uno y otro.

Comment: De lo que tengo entendido es que utilizando el fetch() de javascript puedes mostrar en tiempo real los datos que tienes en una base de datos

Comment: Como dice @MauricioContreras lo que tienes es una gran confusión y eso se refleja en el modo mismo de plantear la pregunta. PHP es una cosa y Javascript es otra. Y tú puedes comunicar entre uno y otro usando la API Fetch de Javascript ciertamente, o Ajax... pero no recibes datos *en tiempo real* ... pero ese no es el asunto aquí. Habiendo entendido que PHP es una cosa y que Javascript es otra, dinos ahora cuál es tu problema... Debes tener claro que **no puedes usar `number_format` de PHP en Javascript**. Si no te gusta como PHP ha formateado los datos tienes dos opciones:

Comment: 1. Haces que PHP formatee los datos como los quieres en Javascript, si esto es posible; o 2. Los formateas en Javascript, al modo de Javascript, o sea, usando funciones propias de Javascript. Un pequeño ejemplo: si en PHP tú haces esto: `echo "1"+"1";`  vas a tener `2` en salida, mientras que en Javascript `cosole.log("1"+"1");` vas a tener `11` en salida... Pues eso, PHP es una cosa y Javascript es otra. Si no entiendes eso, estarás perdido...

Comment: ok, ya comprendí este tema; y para la concatenación de las variables utilizando ese formato es posible hacerlo de esa manera?